# Pull different size of Products and availability from URL to Google sheet

Tags: google-sheets-formula

Hello Everyone I am trying to extract Different sizes available for all product from URL to googlesheet but it is Showing N/A everytime when I try to get it using IMPORTXML. I am copy xpath from rightclick and Paste it into formula still not able to extract information. URL is safguard.com where all the safety shoes can be ordered.
Please find below Link:https://www.safgard.com/mens-shoes?min_price=0&max_price=0&records_per_page=36&current_page=1&order_by_column=purchases_last_six_months&order_by_modifier=DESC&gender=M

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generate a separate product Link and then create xpath for class Labels which will pull all the sizes for all the products. Apart from that it will directly redirect to the page for convenience.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=INDEX(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(QUERY(FLATTEN(IMPORTDATA(A1)), 
 "where Col1 starts with '$'", 0), "\$\d+.\d+")))
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Player0 I was able to get price, style image but i am unable to get Sizes like different sizes available for ALL products starting number, 5,6,7,8,9,8and half, 9 and half, 10, 10 and half, 11 something like that.Please help me with that.

Comment: Never mind I figured it out. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

You can use https://simplescraper.io/ to scrap and send the data directly to Google Sheet.